# fail to Deploy the service to the Google App Engine flexible environment from maven

Tags: cloud

this is basically from the tutorial that follows google doc "Build an Android App Using Firebase and the App Engine Flexible Environment" the link is at:

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-app-engine-flexible?authuser=2" ,

everything was following along until i had to do "Deploying the service to the App Engine flexible environment", using command:

"mvn clean package appengine:deploy"

I instantly failed with this error message from the terminal:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:deploy (default-cli) on project backend: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:deploy failed: Non zero exit: 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:deploy (default-cli) on project backend: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:deploy failed: Non zero exit: 1

help!!!!!

i tried reconfigure mvn, ran mvn clean install, and also check the latest java version as well as making sure the 'java-home' environment variable, that path,  is linked to the latest jdk version with is 1.8 using command:

JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)"

nothing so far worked

it should build successfully, but instead it returns this error,  btw, the app backend runs fine locally, as soon as it is deployed to the cloud, this happened!!!

HELP!!!

Comment: i am following all the steps here, just dont why this would ever happened to me or how this happened at all...

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-app-engine-flexible?authuser=2